# SVG — radial gradient with a smooth edged cutout

Tags: svg

I'm trying to create a SVG background image like this (two colors, radial gradient, S-shape cutout with smooth edges):

[image]

It's quite easy to create a radial gradient (e.g. using [this tool](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/testdrive/demos/svgradientbackgroundmaker/)):

```
<!-- SVG syntax --> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<radialGradient id="g920" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="5.408560311284047%" cy="0%" r="93.04166277718278%">
<stop stop-color="#ed1c24" offset="0.1"/><stop stop-color="#003663" offset="1"/>
</radialGradient>
<rect x="-50" y="-50" width="101" height="101" fill="url(#g920)" />
</svg>
```

but is it possible to add the cutout too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lennis' answer was close.  But you would get better results by combining the fill and the filter in one element, rather than try to use a blurry white shape to hide part of the gradient.

Note that the blur will affect any edge of the shape, including the top, left and right.  So you need to make sure those edges are well away from (outside of) the edge of the SVG viewport.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="g" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="5.4%" cy="0%" r="93%">
      <stop stop-color="#ed1c24" offset="0.1"/>
      <stop stop-color="#003663" offset="0.8"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation=".05" />
    </filter> 
  </defs>
  <path id="svg_1" d="M -0.5,-0.5
                      L 1.5,-0.5
                      L 1.5,0.5
                      L 1,0.5
                      C 1,0 0.6,0.1 0.5,0.25
                      C 0.4,0.4 0.1,0.4 0,0.25
                      L -0.5,0.25
                      Z"
        fill="url(#g)" filter="url(#f1)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a blur on a white element to make it look like a cutout.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="g" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="5.4%" cy="0%" r="93%">
      <stop stop-color="#ed1c24" offset="0.1"/>
      <stop stop-color="#003663" offset="1"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation=".05" />
    </filter> 
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#g)" />
  <path id="svg_1" fill="white" d="m-0.1,0.5 l0,0.55l1.15,0l0,-0.53495c0,0 -0.1,-0.1 -0.5,0c-0.3,0.1 -0.5,0 -0.5,0l-0.1,0z" filter="url(#f1)"/>
</svg>
```

You could also try a [meshgradient](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/pservers.html#MeshGradients), it's in the svg 2.0 spec. At the moment no browser supports it that I know off.